# How to remove [] on __repr__ return

Tags: python, repr

When using **repr** to test the class that I have created, I always get brackets around my printed value.

ex)

```
def __repr__(self):
    return ("H")
```

runs in shell as
[H, H, H, H] for 4 lines. I want to remove the brackets and the commas but am unsure how to do this using **repr**. Do i need to create another method that **repr** returns instead?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not very clear, but I think the following code might demonstrate what you want:

```
>>> class Example:

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'H'


>>> array = [Example() for _ in range(4)]
>>> array
[H, H, H, H]
>>> class ArrayWithoutBrackets(list):

    def __repr__(self):
        return super().__repr__()[1:-1]


>>> array = ArrayWithoutBrackets()
>>> for _ in range(4):
    array.append(Example())


>>> array
H, H, H, H
```

Answer (score 0):

you must hide some thing. i think you have a list to contain all your instances, that's why you see a pair of `[`, `]`.

i don't have any such issue.

```
>>> class A:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "a"


>>> 
>>> A()
a
```

i think this seems to be your situation:

```
>>> [A(),A()]
[a, a]
```